# War not deployed into Wildfly 10.1

Tags: maven, jboss

My war application is not deployed into WildFly 10.1.

Here's the log:

```
16:43:08,875 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "apontatouch.war" (runtime-name: "apontatouch.war")
16:43:09,315 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
16:43:09,932 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-1) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Chakra' 8.2.4.Final
16:43:10,144 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
16:43:10,169 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
16:43:10,177 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
16:43:10,179 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
16:43:10,185 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
16:43:10,186 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
16:43:10,653 INFO  [org.jboss.as.protocol] (management task-10) WFLYPRT0057:  cancelled task by interrupting thread Thread[management-handler-thread - 1,5,management-handler-thread]
16:43:10,688 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on 127.0.0.1:8443
16:43:11,051 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.1.5.Final (Apache CXF 3.1.6) 
16:43:18,215 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment apontatouch.war
16:43:18,432 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-1) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.2.4.Final
16:43:18,933 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver (version 4.0)
16:43:18,996 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-4) WELD-000900: 2.3.5 (Final)
16:43:19,068 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = apontatouch.war_com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver_4_0
16:43:20,438 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (Weld Thread Pool -- 4) WELD-001125: Illegal bean type interface java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<?>,class java.lang.Object> ignored on [EnhancedAnnotatedTypeImpl] public @Named @ApplicationScoped class br.com.caelum.vraptor.view.LinkToHandler
16:43:20,544 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (Weld Thread Pool -- 4) WELD-001125: Illegal bean type com.google.common.collect.ForwardingMap<java.lang.Class<?>, java.lang.Object> ignored on [EnhancedAnnotatedTypeImpl] public @Named @ApplicationScoped class br.com.caelum.vraptor.view.LinkToHandler
16:43:21,762 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "apontatouch.war")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.undertow.server.default-server.aponta"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.aponta./.UndertowDeploymentInfoService is missing [jboss.undertow.server.default-server.aponta]",
        "jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.aponta./ is missing [jboss.undertow.server.default-server.aponta]"
    ]
}
16:43:21,805 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "apontatouch.war" (runtime-name : "apontatouch.war")
16:43:21,847 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.undertow.server.default-server.aponta (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.aponta./, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.aponta./.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 

16:43:22,087 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
16:43:22,088 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
16:43:22,088 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: WildFly Full 10.1.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.2.0.Final) started (with errors) in 23335ms - Started 807 of 1059 services (3 services failed or missing dependencies, 404 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
16:43:22,156 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = apontatouch.war_com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver_4_0
16:43:23,793 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment apontatouch.war (runtime-name: apontatouch.war) in 1661ms
16:43:23,889 WARN  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0357: Notification of type deployment-undeployed is not described for the resource at the address []
16:43:23,919 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDR0002: Content removed from location C:\Users\luis.infoture\Desktop\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\standalone\data\content\0f\38194460d90047fd70e65c404eef0bf7418570\content
16:43:23,920 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYSRV0009: Undeployed "apontatouch.war" (runtime-name: "apontatouch.war")
16:43:23,937 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
```

Here's my `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>br.com.schmersal.svm</groupId>
    <artifactId>apontatouch</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <description>SVM Apontatouch para Android</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <weld.version>2.1.2.Final</weld.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- VRaptor -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.com.caelum</groupId>
            <artifactId>vraptor</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0-RC5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thoughtworks.paranamer</groupId>
            <artifactId>paranamer</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.com.caelum.vraptor</groupId>
            <artifactId>vraptor-jodatime</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0-RC3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- fim VRaptor -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time-hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
            <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.CR1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrpc-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator-cdi</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
            <version>0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- hibernate -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- fim hibernate -->
    </dependencies>



        <build>


        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

What's the problem, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need default host at all? or only the virtual on?

you should be fine by doing something like this:

```
<server name="default-server" default-host="aponta">
                <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http"/>
              <host name="aponta" alias="localhost" default-web-module="apontatouch.war">
                    <location name="/" handler="welcome-content" /> 
                </host>
</server>
```

or if you need default-host, then you just need to add host different allias.

maybe aponta.local, and then add in your hosts file on your machine entry

127.0.0.1 aponta.local (or what ever you decide to call your custom local domain)

on linux this file is located in /etc/hosts
on windows in c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts